# Sql server xml parse

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

Please find below the script snippet

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<Message>

<MessageData>
  <MessageDataSet >
  <id> 1 </id>
  <name>Vasan</name>     
  </MessageDataSet>  
   <MessageDataSet >

    <id> 2 </id>
    <name>Vivek</name>
  </MessageDataSet>  

</MessageData>

</Message>'

SELECT
t.c.value('(id)[1]','varchar(100)')
from
@xml.nodes('/Message/MessageData/MessageDataSet')  AS t(c)
```

I am getting all the 'id' node values, that is '1' & '2'. My need, I have to directly fetch the value of the  second 'id', in this case.it will be '2'. Can anyone let me know the Select query syntax for the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT
    @xml.value('(/Message/MessageData/MessageDataSet/id)[2]','varchar(100)')
```

Returns `2` as the value for me. This grabs the exactly second entry inside that XML - if it's not there, you'll get NULL back.

Also: why convert this to a `varchar(100)` - wouldn't `int` be a more appropriate type here??

Comment: @mark_s, sorry missed to answer your other query, the varchar(100) was just a stop gap stuff, you are right, I will be using the appropriate type.